# Windows 10 Universal Merged Dictionaries

Tags: xaml, uwp

So I have a Windows Universal Class Library that has a resource dictionary in it that I want to merge with my Windows 10 Universal Application's main resource dictionary in App.xaml.

My App.xaml simply merges in my main Resource dictionary from the same assembly.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then from my main resource dictionary (Styles/Styles.xaml) I am merging in other resource dictionaries from the same assembly. This is where I would like to merge in a resource dictionary from another assembly:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Fields.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplates.xaml"/>
    <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="/{AssemblyName};component/Shared.xaml" />-->
    <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{AssemblyName};component/Shared.xaml" />-->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///{AssemblyName}/Shared.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I've tried adding this to my main resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/{AssemblyName};component/Shared.xaml" />
```

and this...

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///{AssemblyName}/Shared.xaml" />
```

Based on [this article](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=718) about Windows 8.x Store Apps this seems like how it **should** work. But it still doesn't work.

and this...

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{AssemblyName};component/Shared.xaml" />
```

(this is the WPF way, I know, but I thought I would give it a try anyway!)

But none seem to work...

The build action of the resource dictionaries that I have in my application assembly are set to 'Page'. These resource dictionaries are working simply using this in the merge:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
```

I get the following cryptic error:

> Failed to assign to property
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source' because the type
>   'Windows.Foundation.String' cannot be assigned to the type
>   'Windows.Foundation.Uri'. [Line: 12 Position: 37]

Comment: Have you added your library as a reference to the project? I'm using `<ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///MyLibrary/Resources.xaml"/>` and it seems to work without problems.

Comment: How are you adding this resource dictionary to the merged dictionary? What happens then?

Comment: Yes, {AssemblyName} is added as a reference to my application's project :)

Comment: What do you guys have the build action set to on the resource dictionary in the other assembly?

Comment: OK, it appears that it does work with what you suggested Romasz. I'm not sure how but I suspect when I was trying all the different combinations of build action / Source URI I must've set the build action to something other than Page when I was trying that technique.

Answer (score 8):

As Romasz mentioned in comment, you need to reference the project which including the styles. And then using the following code to reference.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///UserControlLibs/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image]

Comment: In the example you gave, let's assume you want UserControlLibs to be a nugget package. In that case, how can you merge the resource dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

XAML Merged Dictionaries are trickier than they seem. All is well if you are referencing a local project, then your Source= paths well.

If you are referencing an **external** DLL (not in-solution), the referenced DLL folder must also have all *.xml, *.xr.xml, *.xbf, *.jpg/png/gif, etc.

The procedure I follow is:
1. Reference DLL containing the merged dictionaries (XAML style sheets).
2. Ensure the reference path has all required files.
3. Add the merged dictionary reference to your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///NAMESPACE_HERE/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This PostBuild.bat file describes how I have VS copy all required files on successful build:

```
Echo Starting: PostBuildEvent: Call $(ProjectDir)PostBuild.Bat $(ProjectDir) $(OutDir) $(TargetPath) $(RootNameSpace)
Echo With Parameters: %1 %2 %3 %4

REM ***
REM *** Variables
REM ***
SET BuildLocationBin=..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\bin

REM ***
Echo *** Publish to Bin
REM ***
MD %BuildLocationBin%
%WINDIR%\system32\attrib.exe %BuildLocationBin%\*.* -r /s
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1Properties\*.rd.xml %BuildLocationBin%\%4\Properties\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.png %BuildLocationBin%\%4\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.xbf %BuildLocationBin%\%4\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.xml %BuildLocationBin%\%4\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %3 %BuildLocationBin%\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.pri %BuildLocationBin%\*.* /s/r/y

Echo *** Postbuild Complete ***
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found out that checking "Generate library layout", an option you'll find in Properties | Build, actually places the files to the right locations.